# when dragging horizontally from jsplumb endpoints, arrow head direction changes to opposite direction

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsplumb

I'm having this strange behavior in my program. I'm using jsPlumb flowchart functionality to create connections. Following is my arrow definition:

```
var instance = jsPlumb.getInstance({
    // default drag options
    DragOptions : {
        cursor : 'pointer',
        zIndex : 2000
    },
    ConnectionOverlays : [ [ "Arrow", {
                              location : 1
                         } ],  ],
    Container : "droppable"
});
```

And I have added four drag points for a item. And when ever I drag horizontally, the arrow head direction does not point to the dragging direction. But in vertical drag it works fine. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can any one please help me on this? im still struggling with it

Comment: i found the solution , there is a bug in location : 1, and when its change it to 0.9 it works.